# i want to remove the line breaks in a text file using perl script

Tags: command-line, text-processing, perl

[image]

can this be achieved using perl one liners?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
perl -pne '$_=~s/\n//g; $_=~s/\+//g; END{print "\n";}' filename.txt
```

Explanation:

- `perl -pne` reads the file line-wise, performs the commands given and outputs the content of `$_`
- `comp;` removes the newline character at the end of the line
- `$_=~s/\+//g;` removes the `+` sign from the line
- `END{print "\n";}` adds a newline at the end of the file